# what is the size of the ROM you could use to program for 16 bit adder/subtractor with Cin and Cout?

Tags: logic, addition, subtraction

i searched this in internet i could not find it please any help in solving this

Comment: anyway, how many data bits are being input into the adder/subtractor? .... how many data bits are the output?

Comment: @jsotola thanks for your time i found the answer i will post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer

```
Number of inputs = 16(A) + 16(B) + 1(Cin) = 33 address bits
Number of outputs = 16(sum/diff) + 1(Cout) = 17 
Thus, this would require a 2^33 x 17-bit ROM.
```

here is the reference [click here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjn5vnjpsntAhWBheYKHfHuAuUQFjABegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooksite.elsevier.com%2F9780128000564%2Fcontent%2FDDCAarm_solutions_odd_Chaps1-8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw23jl-WBKIxp5FuwcRzmk4P)  to download the solution by  David Money Harris page number 181 exercise 5.57 a)